# How to find when a TFS Job was created

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am wonderding if there is a way to find out (through API preferably) when projects on a tfs server was created in psudo-real time (Specifically, tfs paths and git repositories). The closest I've gotten is to find the earliest push of every project, but any code I can think of would take too long. Here's my thought process:

- Get Tfs API for list of all jobs
- Go to the url of every job
- Substring search for earliest commit

is there any way I can send only one api request and get the dates from the response? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2013/02/13/tfs2012-new-tools-for-tfs-administrators/)  for TFS Administrators which can monitor job status through

```
http://your-server:8080/tfs/_oi/
```

[image]
Built-in to TFS is the TFS Background Job Agent. This job agent is responsible for the scheduling and queuing of maintenance jobs and other jobs within TFS.  More detailed info you can refer this blog from MSDN: **[How to see activity and job history in TFS 2012](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2013/03/30/how-to-see-activity-and-job-history-in-tfs-2012/)**

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but I'm more looking for a list of all repos and when each repo was created, not job builds